# How to find the middle position between two given position in a 2D array

Tags: java, optimization, logic

I have a 2D array where I want to find the middle position between two given position:
below eg shows the indexes at each position.

```
00, 01, 02, 03
10, 11, 12, 13
20, 21, 22, 23
30, 31, 32, 33
```

Inputs:

- For position `23` and `33` I should get the output position `31`.
  Here the inputs are iStart is 2 and jStart is 3, similarly iEnd is 3 and jEnd is 3
  The expected o/p is i_mid = 3 and j_mid = 1
- For position `00` and `22` I should get the output position `11`.
  Here the inputs are  iStart is 0 and jStart is also 0, similarly iEnd and jEnd are equal to 1
  The expected o/p is i_mid = 1 and j_mid = 1
- For position `02` and `23` I should get the output position `12`. 
  Here the inputs are iStart is 0 and jStart is 2, similarly iEnd is 2 and jEnd is 3
  The expected o/p is i_mid = 1 and j_mid = 2
- For position `10` and `31` I should get the output position `20`.
  Here the inputs are iStart is 3 and jStart is 1, similarly iEnd is 3 and jEnd is 1
  The expected o/p is i_mid = 2 and j_mid = 0

I released that to calculate we should also know the length of the array as it is `n`x`m` matrix, ie. max value of `i` can go is `n` and max value of `j` can go is `m`.
therefor for a `n`x`m` array `iMax` will be `n` and `jMax` will be `m`

Now the function can be represents as:

```
void getMiddle(int iStart, int jStart, int iEnd, int jEnd, int iMax, int jMax) {


 //We need to find the mid_i and mid_j of the input positions
 System.out.println("midd_i = "+ mid_i +" and midd_j = "+mid_j);
}
```

I solved this via a brute force approach, however I'm looking for an optimal solution.

In my approach, first I find the number of elements that can come between the given position and then I divided the number of element by 2 and traverse the position till half of the elements that can come as that point will be the mid, my solution is as followed:

```
void getMiddle(int iStart, int jStart, int iEnd, int jEnd, int jMax) {
   int numberOfRows = (iEnd - iStart) + 1;
   int totalElementsInRows = jMax * numberOfRows;
   int eliminateStartElements = jStart;
   int eliminateEndElements = (jMax - 1) - jEnd;
   int totalElementsPresentBetweenPositions = totalElementsInRows - (eliminateStartElements + eliminateEndElements);
   int halfElement = totalElementsPresentBetweenPositions/2;
   int countElement = 0;
   for(int i = iStart; i<= iEnd; i++) {
      for(int j = 0; j< jMax; j++) {
        countElement++;
        if(halfElement == countElement) {
          System.out.println("midd_i = "+ i +" and midd_j = "+j);
          break;
        }
      }
  }
}
```

I'm sure there should be an optimal solution, If anyone have the optimal solution, please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's a wrong approach, please see the comment section below.

////////////////////////////

You can find the average between the points. When you have point A and point B. The program has to compute average in two dimensions: `x=(Ax + Bx)/2`. Similarly in the y-axis.

You don't have to worry about .5 appended to end of the number, because Java will truncate it for you.

Comment: I tried to understand, however this will not help, as there is a huge gap between the expected solution, eg. take the first position as 23 and second position 33, it will never reach to the mid position, you can check the inputs in question with expected output

Comment: Ok, can you tell me what should it produce? You didn't show that test case. My approach would give 23, but what's the real result?

Comment: Ok I don't understand the question then. Sorry for answering without understanding.

Comment: The problem is dependent on the size of the matrix that is mxn, here m=3 and n is also = 3. so to find the mid these are the two important factor, to make is simple I have taken m=n=3.

Comment: Ok, you want to rearrange the matrix. And find midpoint in "one" dimension?

Comment: Yes you can say that, if you append each new line to the previous line, it will look like 1D array however still the logic says its 2D array as the first dimension end at the index 3.

Comment: I think you can check how many rows you can go forward by dividing halfElement by row size, then, i+=halfElement/row_size. countElement -= (halfElement/row_size)*row_size

Comment: This goes from O(mn) to O(n). And next you can do the same from the other side to achieve O(1)

Comment: So you can go j+=halfElement-countElement, then if j>row_size then (i++; j-=row_size)

Comment: This is the brut force approach that I already mentioned in the question, I'm looking for an optimal way.

Comment: It was O(1).i+=halfelement/row_size; countelement+=(halfElement/row_size)*row_size; j+=halfElement-countelement; if(I >row_size){i++; j-=row_size}

Answer (score 0):

There should be a way to do this with a geometric approach...

Find the midpoint between the two you want to get, so if you wanted to find the position between mat[0][0] and mat[2][2], you find the midpoints:

mid = (Math.abs(x1 - x2) / 2, Math.abs(y1 - y2) / 2)

x = (2 - 0) / 2 = 1
y = (2 - 0) / 2 = 1

so the answer there would be mat[1][1]

if it were a less straightforward example, such as mat[0][2] and mat[3][3]:

we first find the midpoint, such as:

x = (3 - 0) / 2 = 1.5
y = (3 - 2) / 2 = 0.5

round the answers to the nearest whole number to get the right indexes

Comment: This is not a geometric graph problem its a 2D matrix problem, you can verify your solution by the given inputs in the question with the mentioned output.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the task by imagining concrete numbers in the respective positions instead of the indices, which range from `0 to n x m - 1`. Something like :

```
 0,  1,  2,  3
 4,  5,  6,  7
 8,  9, 10, 11
12, 13, 14, 15
```

Then for each elemnt at m[i][j] applies

```
m[i][j] = i * m[i].length + j
```

and for each k, `0 <= k < n x m`

```
 i = k / m
 j = k % m
```

which sums up in your method looking like:

```
static void getMiddle(int iStart, int jStart, int iEnd, int jEnd, int iMax, int jMax) {
    int s = iStart * jMax + jStart;
    int e = iEnd * jMax + jEnd;
    int mid_i = ((e+s)/2)/jMax;
    int mid_j = ((e+s)/2)%jMax;
    System.out.println("midd_i = "+ mid_i +" and midd_j = "+mid_j);
}
```

Note: I'm not checking for valid inputs, for example if `iStart <= iEnd <= iMax`

Test out put with your input example:

```
getMiddle(0, 0, 2, 2, 4, 4);
getMiddle(0, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4);
getMiddle(1, 0, 3, 1, 4, 4);

midd_i = 1 and midd_j = 1
midd_i = 1 and midd_j = 2
midd_i = 2 and midd_j = 0
```